# SCP: Send file to computer on a different network

Tags: linux, networking, windows, scp

I am trying to send a file from my Windows computer that is connected to my home network to another Linux computer on a different network.

I have tried:

```
scp file user@ip-address:/home/Documents
```

I used the ip-address that I got from doing ifconfig on my Linux machine. I also tried using my public ip. No luck in both cases.This is the error I get:

> Fatal: Network Error: Connection Timed Out

The public ip is not working because both computers are behind a router so I think I am getting the public ip from the router, not the computer.

If other method is applicable to this case, please lmk.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The linux machine might be behind a NAT-router. If that's the case the most straight forward solution is to forward the port (22 is the standard for SSH) on the router to the linux machine, If you have sufficient access to a third machine you can copy the file via that, either by two `scp`'s or by setting up a VPN server on it, and connect both he windows and the linux machine as clients.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will take a look to see if it is a NAT router. I do not have access to a third machine. Could hamachi also be a choice to transfer files between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Given that SCP was giving problems, I had to use DROPBOX API to upload the file to DROPBOX from computer A and download it using this same API on Computer B.